# Pad array values with parentheses to perform insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I want to have each array value inside a paranthesis

```
$id   = $_POST['id'];
$test2 = array($id);
$id_list = implode(',', $test2);
$sql .= "INSERT INTO tmp (id) VALUES ({$id_list});";
```

for example: I'm performing an insert so the output of the list should be (5),(10),(15) not '5','10','15'

Any suggestions on how I can insert using an array?

Comment: `'(' . implode('),(', $test2) .')'` but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1|25.1876

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's extended insert syntax is

```
INSERT INTO sometable (...fields...) VALUES (value set #1), (value set #2), (value set #3), etc...
```

Note how each value set is in its own `()`. You're not doing that. you're just passing a bunch of values in a SINGLE `()` set, which means you're providing values for fields that are NOT present in the field list.

You need to do

```
$id_list = '(' . implode('),(', $_POST['id']) . ')';
```

producing

```
(5),(10),(15)
```

instead of

```
(5, 10, 15)
```

You also need to realize that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: The code you gave me produces the output (5, 10, 15).  I'm having trouble getting the parenthesis in between the commas

Comment: then is `$_POST['id']` actually an array? e.g. your form contains multiple `<input name="id[]" ... />` tags? because doing `array($_POST['id'])` does NOT magically split a string up into multiple values for you to implode again later. you'd need to `explode()` the string first.